# How to display loading image while actual image is downloading

Tags: jquery

Sometimes images take some time to render in the browser. I want to show a busy image while the actual image is downloading, and when the image is downloaded, the busy image is removed and the actual image should be shown. How can I do this with JQuery or any javascript?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// show loading image
$('#loader_img').show();

// main image loaded ?
$('#main_img').on('load', function(){
  // hide/remove the loading image
  $('#loader_img').hide();
});
```

You assign `load` event to the image which fires when image has finished loading. Before that, you can show your loader image.

Comment: I have also used this technique and it works really well.  Just remember to handle the error and abort cases...

Comment: @WearetheWorld add handler for the error event. you can do something like `$(img).load(handler).error(handler)`. @see http://api.jquery.com/error/.

Comment: Would this work for class selector? Like `.images`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `.load` in this context has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8. For more recent version of jQuerys, use `.on('load', function(){ /* blah */ });` instead.

Comment: Sarfraz, you can update your answer with @Fluoxetine 's comment. So it can still be a great answer

Comment: how do achieve the same with multiple images?

Answer (score 164):

Just add a background image to all images using css:

```
img {
  background: url('loading.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It should help in ADF Applications where javascript exceution is nondeterministic due to partial page rendering. I will give a try for sure :-).

Comment: Hmm, if an image has transparent areas, then background still can be seen after the image has already loaded.

Comment: @Martin transparent images, indeed, won't work.

Comment: Although a JS Script when page loads to take away the background image will work.

Comment: this doesn't work for responsive images, you need to set image size in order to show the background

Comment: If you want the background image to take up the full size of the image you should add `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: @WilliamHampshire You can also use `background-size: cover;` or `background-size:contain;` if you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the image, but still have it full-size.

Answer (score 11):

I use a similar technique to what @Sarfraz posted, except instead of hiding elements, I just manipulate the class of the image that I'm loading.

```
<style type="text/css">
.loading { background-image: url(loading.gif); }
.loaderror { background-image: url(loaderror.gif); }
</style>
...
<img id="image" class="loading" />
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        i = document.getElementById('image');
        i.removeAttribute('class');
        i.src = img.src;
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('class', 'loaderror');
    };
    img.src = 'http://path/to/image.png';
</script>
```

In my case, sometimes images don't load, so I handle the onerror event to change the image class so it displays an error background image (rather than the browser's broken image icon).

Comment: This is different - you're loading the image _outside_ the page DOM then moving it onto the `img` element from the browser cache. The method might not work if the image has some sort of _no caching_ HTTP response header.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of just doing this quoted method from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635440/3787376,

> You can do something like this:
>
> ```
> // show loading image
> $('#loader_img').show();
>
> // main image loaded ?
> $('#main_img').on('load', function(){
>   // hide/remove the loading image
>   $('#loader_img').hide();
> });
> ```
>
> You assign `load` event to the image which fires when image has
>   finished loading. Before that, you can show your loader image.

you can use a different jQuery function to make the loading image fade away, then be hidden:

```
// Show the loading image.
$('#loader_img').show();

// When main image loads:
$('#main_img').on('load', function(){
  // Fade out and hide the loading image.
  $('#loader_img').fadeOut(100); // Time in milliseconds.
});
```

> "Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none."
>   http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Or you could not use the jQuery library because there are already simple cross-browser JavaScript methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript constructor with a callback that fires when the image has finished loading in the background. Just used it and works great for me cross-browser. Here's the [thread with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088850/1285185).