# jQuery image loading icon

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make it so when a picture is not yet loaded it will add an icon on top of the image.

Here's what I have done, I can't really say anything else that it is not doing what it is supposed to do so.

```
$(".loading").show();

$(".img").load(function(){

    $(".loading").hide();
});
```

Index:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

Apparently i made it work by rewriting my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".loading").show();

    $('.img').on('load', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".loading").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: what issue you have faced?

Comment: Try adding the JS code on `$(window).load(..);`. Also try other answers given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading.

Comment: @ShaunakD Already tried, but I can't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: @JqueryKing For some reason it only displays the .loading for a secound.

Comment: Won't work properly if there are more than one `class="img"`. WIll fire when any of them load

Comment: @charlietfl There's more than one class="img" how do i make it so it works on all images who has that class?