# Load image only when opening the modal in Laravel

Tags: laravel, image-loading

**Description**

I have a small preview picture and when clicking on it, a modal opens with a bigger image.

```
<a onClick="ToggleImage()" class="toggle-img-btn">
<img class="about-img" src="{{asset("storage/images/about_170.jpg")}}" /></a>

@include('inc.imageModal')
```

And the image modal:

```
<div class="img-modal-background" id="img-modal-background">
  <div class="img-modal-content">
    <input type="checkbox" class="img-close" onClick="ToggleImage()" />
    <a class="img-close-cross"></a>
    <img class="modal-img" src="{{asset("storage/images/about.jpg")}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript function for opening/closing the modal:

```
function ToggleImage() {
    const modalBG = document.getElementById("img-modal-background");
    const modalIMG = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
    if (modalBG.style.display === "flex") {
        modalBG.style.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(() => {
            modalBG.style.display = "none";
            modalIMG.style.display = "none";
        }, 500);
    } else {
        modalBG.style.display = "flex";
        modalIMG.style.display = "inherit";
        setTimeout(() => {
            modalBG.style.opacity = "1";
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

**Question**

I only want to load the image in the modal, when the user opens the modal.

How can i achieve this?

I use Laravel 7 and plain JS.

You can find the repo [here](https://gitlab.com/leonp5/bueffelhilfe/-/tree/master)

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: use `data-src` on your image and use this code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525803/4258328

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
If i see it right, it is the same approach Ahmed is suggesting.

Comment: yes kindof similar, his code works well for a single image 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put your image path on js variable and set attribute img src depend modal status like this :

```
function ToggleImage() {
const modalBG = document.getElementById("img-modal-background");
const modalIMG = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
const img = "storage/images/about.jpg";

if (modalBG.style.display === "flex") {
    modalBG.style.opacity = "0";
    modalIMG.setAttribute("src", "");
    setTimeout(() => {
        modalBG.style.display = "none";
        modalIMG.style.display = "none";
    }, 500);
} else {
    modalBG.style.display = "flex";
    modalIMG.style.display = "inherit";
    modalIMG.setAttribute("src", img);
    setTimeout(() => {
        modalBG.style.opacity = "1";
    }, 10);
}
```

}