# Show the loader upto loading the background image for a div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I set a background image for a `div`. But, I want to show the loader up to loading a background image for a `<div/>` in jQuery.

Comment: please write what have you tried?

Comment: sorry I have no idea.

Comment: are you loading the image via jquery?

Comment: yes. i load image through jquery.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading and http://network.convergenceservices.in/forum/51-jquery-and-ajax/1865-showing-loader-while-images-are-loading-using-simple-jquery.html

Comment: you should mention what you tried so far and also search about your problem before asking, there are many possible duplicates of this question already

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#imgLoader').show();
  $('#imgMain').load(function(){
    $('imgLoader').hide();
  });
});
```

Here imgLoader is the image which you want to show when the main image (imgMain) is loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image with jQuery using the `load` function.

for example:

```
$("<img src='pathtoimg/img.jpg'>").load(function(){
    //any code in here will run after the image has successfully loaded.
});
```

Comment: i want show a loader befor the background image is getting load.