# Adding hourglass image while processing url-Dropwizard & Java

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard & Java.I am having a url http://locolhost:9090/project/new 
After processing this url, it will return a message from java class.

I need to include hourglass image and a message ,when the page loads.Then,after processing, it should show the return message.If anyone knows,please help me to code.

Comment: You can try using jquery on loading. Just like what is done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading).

Comment: I didnt use any css, jquery,html.I am very new to this.Given only path with return type.How can I add this function to my resource path.