# Difference between [src] and src in Angular2

Tags: image, angular

In Angular1,

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

This will hide the broken image icon if the imageUrl is empty.

But in Angular2, both

```
<img src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

and the equivalent of ngSrc

```
<img [src]="imageUrl">
```

still show the small broken image icon as the image placeholder if imageUrl is empty.

What's the actual difference there?

Comment: set a background image with loading icon for image tag, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4635498/2435473), or Rather use `alt` tag until image isn't there it will show `Text` from `alt` attribute

Comment: I don't see here the small broken image icon https://plnkr.co/edit/IhJk0eTdFUZFTsZOfPpT?p=preview

Comment: The broken image placeholder appears only on Firefox apparently. Though I'm not sure why plunker behaves like Chrome there.

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally add your `img` by using [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

```
<img *ngIf="imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl">
```

Answer (score 2):

`[src]="imageUrl"` is property binding that assigns the value of `imageUrl` to the `src` property. This works with all kind of values.

`src="{{imageUrl}}"` also does property binding but `{{}}` does string interpolation, this means that `imageUrl` is stringified before it's assigned to the `src` property. Don't use this style if you want to pass objects or arrays, or boolean.

When DomSanitizer is used `[src]="..."` is mandatory because the value no longer is a string, but an object and using `{{}}` would stringify it in an invalid way.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is only semantics for your use case.

Using the interpolation option `<img src="{{imageUrl}}">` tells angular to put the value of imageUrl into that place holder.  In your case, insert it into the value of `src` property.

Using the template expression option `<img [src]="imageUrl">` tells angular to explicitly set the value of the `src` property to the value of `imageUrl`.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: No problem, just making sure my explanation was clear.  You made me re-read it...