# Force an img to re-download from the same URL

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using randomly-generated images from this API: http://loremflickr.com/320/240

When the application starts, it takes a random image using that link.

When I click on a button, I want to update the image by setting the `img src` -- but the URL is the same, so the browser sees the same link so does not call the api, so a new random image isn't generated.

Here is the html code:

```
<img style="float:right;position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);" src="{{gifLoader}}"/>
```

The button has a click event which calls this function:

```
nextImg()
  {
    this.gifLoader = "http://loremflickr.com/" + window.screen.width + "/" + window.screen.height;
  }
```

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried.

Comment: I posted the codes

Comment: Just add a simple timestamp as a cache buster ... https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/cachebuster-code-in-javascript/

Comment: When you investigate the DOM in the browsers devtools, do you see the `src="..."` with the expected URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a query parameter like a timestamp. As the timestamp will be different each time it will be considered a new request and you will get a new image each time to update the img `src`

```
this.gifLoader = "http://loremflickr.com/" + window.screen.width + "/" + window.screen.height +"?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Accepted , may I ask another related question
there's a delay period to download the image from the server
how to catch this time , to put a loading gif or anything on this period

Comment: for that you can have a spinner/loader image. just before changing the url set the visibility of that loader image to visible then update the image url and hide the lodaer image on onload event of the image. For reference see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading)

Answer (score 1):

You can try cache buster like mentioned below:-

"http://loremflickr.com/320/240?rnd="+`(new Date()).getTime()`