# Show gif while image is loading (wicket)

Tags: wicket

I am following this guide for displaying images in wicket [How to load external Images](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+load+an+external+image)

I see one problem and dont know how to solve it. Consider this piece of code

```
StaticImage img=new StaticImage( "icon", new Model(loadingGIFURL));
//get real image url
img.setDefaultModel(new Model(realURL))
```

It doesnt show the loading gif, because I override the `DefaultModel`. So how can I still show my loading gif but "preload" the real image and when the real image is downloaded then replace the loading gif with my image.

Note that I dont have a image source like `base64`, I only have the image `url`

Comment: I think this is some kind of I already have. Did you read the link? Changing the src to an URL starts the requests to load the image, but I want to show the gif WHILE it is loading

Comment: Hi, this looks more a problem that you could solve with JavaScript rather than on server side. Check this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635388/how-to-display-loading-image-while-actual-image-is-downloading